# How to POST JSON with Polymer

Tags: ajax, json, post, polymer

I did a cadaster screen with polymer and I want to POST a JSON with the user, password and e-mail. I know that in Polymer have the core-ajax thats can do it, but i didn't understand how to make this work. If someone can help me. The code is below:

```
<div class = "cadastro">
  <template id="user-maintenance" is="auto-binding">

<div>
    <paper-input-decorator id="user" label="Usuário" floatinglabel type="text" value="{{user}}" error="Usuário deve conter apenas letras e no mímino 3">
        <input id="user1" type="text" is="core-input" pattern="^[A-Za-z*]{3,}$" required>
    </paper-input-decorator >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to do a form i first make a polymer element for this example i will call it "my-form".  in that element we will make a created function that will set up our object we are sending to the server. below is a simple version with only 1 input field but should give you a idea how it works.

```
<polymer-element name="my-form">
  <template>
    <div id="invalid">
      <paper-input-decorator
        id="check"
        floatinglabel
        error="Error!!!"
        label="LABEL">
        <input is="core-input" id="data" required committedValue="{{item.firstItem}}" pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9]+$">
      </paper-input-decorator>
      <br>
      <paper-button
        on-tap="{{checkData}}"
        raised>
        Save
      </paper-button>
    </div>
    <core-ajax
      id="ajax"
      auto="false"
      method="POST"
      url="URL"
      handleas="json"
      params='{{item}}'
      response="{{response}}">
    </core-ajax>
    <paper-toast id="toast"></paper-toast>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('my-form', {
      created: function () {
        // sets up the object 
        this.item = {}; 
      },
      checkData: function () {
          // this function will check data of all inputs in the invalid div to make sure it matches data type and pattern
          var $d = this.$.invalid.querySelectorAll('paper-input-decorator'),
            that = this;
          Array.prototype.forEach.call($d, function (d) {
            d.isInvalid = !d.querySelector('input').validity.valid;
          });
          // the timeout gives time to mark as invalid before checking 
          setTimeout(function () {
            // for each input you are checking you will need another variable and also to add the check to the following if statment
            var invalid = that.$.check.classList.contains("invalid");

            if (!invalid) {
               that.$.ajax.go();
            }
          }, 100);
      },
      responseChanged: function () {
        // do something on response i like to use a paper-toast here alerting the user the data has been accepted or rejected
         this.$.toast.text = response;
         this.$.toast.show();
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: I tried to do something like this with my code, but doesn't work, and i tried your code in google designer, but doesn't work too.
I'm very new in this and i doesn't understand why this don't work.

Comment: i looked back over my code and found i had a colon where a semicolon should have been. also if you didn't import the html elements used in this code it will not work. i did not include in my answer as i thought it was implied. i made a Plunker with the working code you can find it here http://plnkr.co/edit/xDJK6BJOmh8Bd0FJGEVk?p=preview

Comment: thanks a lot, i imported the html elements in the firs time. But know seeing the code working i was able to understand. Thanks!!